# What does it mean to develop a proper implementation of the grammar of graphics?

Tags: data-visualization, python

I want to develop an implementation of the grammar of graphics in python, and I need to wrap my head around a few things. I am actually having some difficulties in understanding some of the book's broadest concepts.

For what I understand, a correct implementation of the grammar means that a graphic is defined with its data characteristics instead of being composed (as it is done in the usual plotting libraries). When a plot command is issued, a graphic almost "renders itself".

Is this interpretation correct and sufficient to build a proper implementation of the grammar or am I missing some deeper mathematical concepts?

Edit: The first approach I have in mind is to define a class for a graph, and then have a way to compose into instances of this class: scales, coordinates, aesthetics etc. Also, should I enforce lazy data loading and calculations until the moment a plot is actually required?

Comment: Just an idea but perhaps it would be useful to have a look at Hadley Wickham's implementation of Grammar of Graphics for R for some pointers? [http://ggplot2.org/](http://ggplot2.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I just got the ggplot book yesterday and started looking through it, (it makes a better job at explaining the overall steps that the GoG book), I am confident that I can infer some general assumptions by looking at that code and the descriptions of the different processes. But I also need to have some doubts clarified, and one of those is how much (if any) mathematical consistency this model has, and how can I be sure not to break it. (I have also questions about variables, varsets and the algebra defined in the GoG, but did not want to ask everything in a single question)

Comment: You might want to look at the implementation of this which is already in production, see Bokeh. Project homepage: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/Bokeh Video lecture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_aE0kAedL0

Comment: Why would you do it, instead of just connecting python with ggplot2? Wouldn't that be a simpler solution?